# Optimizing Cookie Clicker garden mutation layout

Tags: recreational-mathematics, discrete-optimization, popular-math

In cookie clicker there is a farming mini game. You can place plants on a grid. To unlock new plants, you have to place 2 plants you already have and on places adjacent to them (3x3 grid) there is a chance a new plant will mutate. We can model the garden as a matrix with elements being either 0 or 1 (or maybe 0, 1, 2, in case we try to mutate different types of plants):
\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}
Here, in places of zeros there is a $p$% chance that a new type of plant will appear.
The total chance that a new type of plant will appear can be calculated with Bernoulli trials:
$1 - (1-\frac{p}{100})^k$, $k$ being the number of zeros.

How to find an optimal setup for an $n \times m$ garden, maximizing the chance of a new mutation appearing, without using brute-force?

I'd appreciate any theorems, literature and so on to learn more about it.

Some optimal examples:
[image]

Comment: By "maximize the chance of a new mutation appearing" do you just mean "maximize the number of empty cells adjacent to placed plants"? And does "adjacent" mean "sharing a side"? If so, an asymptotically optimal solution is to place a plant at the center of each tile in a tiling of the plane by Greek crosses, like the one shown [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreekCross.html).

Comment: Yes, maximize adjecent zeros. Adjecent means sharing a side or a diagonal. I know, that the Greek crosses are not optimal at least up to 6x6.

Comment: If diagonals count, then tile with 3x3 squares instead. The goal is for each zero to be adjacent to exactly one placed plant.

Comment: It needs to be adjacent to at least 2 of them

Comment: Also, I'm more interested in ways to solve such problems, than an outright solution, if possible

Comment: So the actual problem is "for $n\times m$ matrices with $0$ and $1$ entries, which matrices have the maximum number of $0$s possible adjacent (by side or diagonally) to two or more $1$s?"

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  Let $N_{ij}$ denote the set of neighbors of cell $(i,j)$. Let binary decision variable $x_{ij}$ indicate whether there is a plant at cell $(i,j)$.  Let binary decision variable $y_{ij}$ indicate whether cell $(i,j)$ is empty and has at least two neighboring plants.  The problem is to maximize $\sum_{i,j} y_{ij}$ subject to linear constraints
\begin{align}
y_{ij} &\le 1 - x_{ij} &&\text{for all $i$ and $j$} \tag1\label1 \\
2 y_{ij} &\le \sum_{(k,\ell)\in N_{ij}} x_{k\ell} &&\text{for all $i$ and $j$} \tag2\label2
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} forces cell $(i,j)$ to be empty if $y_{ij}=1$.
Constraint \eqref{2} forces at least two neighboring plants if $y_{ij}=1$.

For $n\times n$ grids with $n\in\{1,\dots,15\}$, I get the following maximum values:
$$0,2,6,10,17,26,34,46,60,72,89,108,125,146,170$$